# Critical information should not be stored solely in the title

Tags: discussion

Some questions are appearing with moves in the title, or other critical information, that is not repeated again in the main question, which makes reading the post a little bit confusing.  I propose the reviewers to actively move critical parts of the question (specially moves), to the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on upvotes for the question, the community agrees with you.

(Answer posted to remove question from [unanswered list](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered).)